# ASP.NET + jQuery UI Modal: load aspx page into modal dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I need to load aspx page into jQuery UI's modal dialog window.
I used following approach: load page content via ajax call into dialog's div and show it:

```
$.get('Page.aspx', function(response){
    $('#dialog').html(response);
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
```

but I've got very strange error (IE8) in line 137215738 (!): *'theForm.elements.length' -  is null or not an object*. JS debbuger says that source code is not available for such location. I have an assumption that this error happens because of multiple 'form' tags that appears on page after ajax call

I wonder, how can i fix this? Or maybe some other way of showing aspx page in modal dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot fully embed one ASPX page's content within another for a couple of reasons:

1. You would be nesting `<html>` tags in a non-sensical way.
2. You are polluting one page's javascript state with the other's.

You need to render `Page.aspx` as a partail view, rather than including the entire payload of an ASPX page.

I'm not 100% sure if you can do this in plain-old-asp.net without calling the `Render` function of individual controls, using the Response stream as the target.

In ASP.NET-MVC, however, you *can* use a PartialView result.

Answer (score 6):

What about putting an IFRAME in the modal, and setting the IFRAME src to Page.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

right click on your web project in Visual Studio and add new generic HTTP handler. The code will look like this:

*DialogContentHandler.ashx*:

```
    public class DialogContentHandler: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            string s = getDialogContent();
            context.Response.Write(s);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

aspx code:

```
$.get('DialogContentHandler.ashx', function(response){
    $('#dialog').html(response);
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little what getDialogContent() does? Also, did you have to add any UrlMapping for the HTTPHanlder?

Comment: getDialogContent - is abstract name of a function, which renders html for dialog, for ex.: string getDialogContent() { return "<h1>Hello</h1>"}. As far as I remember - there is  no need to add mappings, as for for ASP.NET (not MVC) route-per-file mapping model works by default (I can be wrong here)

Answer (score -1):

Solved by creating generic HTTP handler and writing to the response only nessesary html markup.